# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token

Tags: c++

New on stack overflow.
So i'm trying to reconstruct everything i learned so far in college and here's the templated node that i'm going to be using to go into a stack/queue

```
template<typename T>
class node{

public:

    node();                        
    node(T data);                   
    ~node();                        

    T           GetData();          
    node        *&GetNext();        
private:

    void        DeleteNode();       //Deletes Node

    T           m_data;             //Template Data
    node        *next;              //next pointer
};

template<typename T> 
node *&node<T>::GetNext() //Error is here
{ 
   return next;
}
```

Error reads as "error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token"

I've tried different variants of moving node and the *& but none seem to work.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe that question could lead us to better help you.

Comment: Taking a reference to a pointer as argument makes sense. Returning a reference to a pointer usually does not. You don't want users of your class to go changing the internal pointers, would you?

Comment: @hlt of course you can have references to pointers and should have one exactly as used there.

Comment: It should return the pointer named next. And the error is not in the *&. I had it properly running in a different iteration where it wasn't in a template.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I was thinking on making it so that the *&GetNext can't change the value of Next but i couldn't figure how to do that. I'll probably figure that out in my own time tho

Comment: @JoshuaLiu Just remove the `&`.

Comment: I think the whole point is that important internal uses of `GetNext` **do** need to be able to change the value.  Maybe you want to split internal uses from external uses.

Comment: @JSF that would be a horrible violation of encapsulation if the user could manually mess with the list structure

Comment: Encapsulation should be a tool, not a religion.  Here, encapsulation horribly gets in the way of developing maintainable code and accomplishes nothing.  The academic kludges that put understanding of the outer structure into the node class are badly flawed.  But otherwise, the class knowing the structure must have more rights inside node than other classes do, which is what `friend` is supposed to be for, but in the real world that use of `friend` is often an unmaintainable mess.  Anway, making `GetNext` private and friending its user is independent of the question asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
node<T> *&node<T>::GetNext()
```

You need that T specified for both the return type and the class containing the function.

Comment: Huh didn't think of that. Why is that necessary? is it due to the fact that the  base structure for node is a template so both require the <T>?

Comment: That definition starts outside the scope of the class, so `node` is not a type.  You need to specify a return type that is a type.  There are some other template situations in which a return type from a template class function can be the same template class with a different template parameter.  So if the language syntax somehow assumed the same template parameter, that would be limiting.